# How to deploy maven war in Plesk version 7.8 in Windows

Tags: maven, plesk

I am working on Spring Hibernate project and using build tool is maven.Iw want to deploy this war in Plesk version 7.8 in windows.There is no option for deploy war.Can anyone help me.

Comment: The following [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760239/how-to-deploy-war-files-in-plesk-onyx-17-8-despite-no-longer-supported-tomcat) could help you.

Comment: No andl i have moved on AWS @ThirstForKnowledge

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant Plesk Onyx 17.8.

Since this version Tomcat is [no longer supported](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005115774) by Plesk.
The most recent Plesk version which includes Tomcat is Plesk Onyx 17.5 and it is supported at least until April 20, 2021.

In order to install older Plesk version, it is required to start Plesk installer with `--all-versions` option, as in:

```
C:\> plesk-installer.exe --console --all-versions
```